# Encrypt message with RSA private key (as in OpenSSL's RSA_private_encrypt)

Tags: go, rsa, pem

I'm trying to implement [Chef API client](http://docs.opscode.com/api_chef_server.html) in Go, but stuck trying to create correct request header RSA signature. According to [documentation](http://docs.opscode.com/api_chef_server.html):

> A canonical header is signed with the private key used by the client machine from which the request is sent, and is also encoded using Base64.

The following ruby call to `OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.private_encrypt()` can be found in `mixlib-authentication` [gem code](https://github.com/opscode/mixlib-authentication/blob/master/lib/mixlib/authentication/signedheaderauth.rb#L94), it uses [OpenSSL bindings](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKey/RSA.html#method-i-private_encrypt), `private_encrypt()` method calls `RSA_private_encrypt` [openssl function](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_private_encrypt.html).

Unfortunately, I cannot find matching function in Go's standard library; [`crypto/rsa`](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/) looks close, but it only implements conventional cryptography methods: encryption with *public* key, hash signing with *private* key. OpenSSL's `RSA_private_encrypt` does the opposite: it encrypts (small) message with private key (akin to creating a signature from message hash).

This "signing" can also be achieved with this command:

```
openssl rsautl -sign -inkey path/to/private/key.pem \
    -in file/to/encrypt -out encrypted/output
```

Are there any native Go libraries to achieve the same result as OpenSSL's `RSA_private_encrypt`, or the only way is using Cgo to call this function from OpenSSL library? Maybe I'm missing something. My idea was implementing the client without any non-go dependencies.

I'm a Go newbie, so I'm not sure I can dive into `crypto/rsa` module sources.

---

Found the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107143/how-do-i-encrypt-with-an-rsa-private-key-read-from-a-pem-file-using-the-go-progr), but [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3114679/229034) to use `SignPKCS1v15` is obviously wrong (this [function encrypts message's hash, not the message itself](http://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#SignPKCS1v15)).

Comment: That Chef API documentation is tragically unclear, but I think you are supposed to sign the headers, which means SignPKCS1v15 is probably what you want.

Comment: @GregS, sadly, this is not the case, I double-checked with [mixlib-authentication sources](https://github.com/opscode/mixlib-authentication/blob/master/lib/mixlib/authentication/signedheaderauth.rb#L94).

Comment: I think you might be correct. I suspect it is using PKCS1 v15 *block type 1* padding, but that really doesn't help you. Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With [great help of the golang community](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Golang-Nuts/Vocj33WNhJQ), the solution was found:

Original code posted at http://play.golang.org/p/jrqN2KnUEM by Alex (see [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Golang-Nuts/Vocj33WNhJQ)).

I've added input block size check as specified in Section 8 of [rfc2313](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2313): http://play.golang.org/p/dGTl9siO8E

Here's the code:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/rsa"
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/pem"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "math/big"
    "os/exec"
)

var (
    ErrInputSize  = errors.New("input size too large")
    ErrEncryption = errors.New("encryption error")
)

func PrivateEncrypt(priv *rsa.PrivateKey, data []byte) (enc []byte, err error) {

    k := (priv.N.BitLen() + 7) / 8
    tLen := len(data)
    // rfc2313, section 8:
    // The length of the data D shall not be more than k-11 octets
    if tLen > k-11 {
        err = ErrInputSize
        return
    }
    em := make([]byte, k)
    em[1] = 1
    for i := 2; i < k-tLen-1; i++ {
        em[i] = 0xff
    }
    copy(em[k-tLen:k], data)
    c := new(big.Int).SetBytes(em)
    if c.Cmp(priv.N) > 0 {
        err = ErrEncryption
        return
    }
    var m *big.Int
    var ir *big.Int
    if priv.Precomputed.Dp == nil {
        m = new(big.Int).Exp(c, priv.D, priv.N)
    } else {
        // We have the precalculated values needed for the CRT.
        m = new(big.Int).Exp(c, priv.Precomputed.Dp, priv.Primes[0])
        m2 := new(big.Int).Exp(c, priv.Precomputed.Dq, priv.Primes[1])
        m.Sub(m, m2)
        if m.Sign() < 0 {
            m.Add(m, priv.Primes[0])
        }
        m.Mul(m, priv.Precomputed.Qinv)
        m.Mod(m, priv.Primes[0])
        m.Mul(m, priv.Primes[1])
        m.Add(m, m2)

        for i, values := range priv.Precomputed.CRTValues {
            prime := priv.Primes[2+i]
            m2.Exp(c, values.Exp, prime)
            m2.Sub(m2, m)
            m2.Mul(m2, values.Coeff)
            m2.Mod(m2, prime)
            if m2.Sign() < 0 {
                m2.Add(m2, prime)
            }
            m2.Mul(m2, values.R)
            m.Add(m, m2)
        }
    }

    if ir != nil {
        // Unblind.
        m.Mul(m, ir)
        m.Mod(m, priv.N)
    }
    enc = m.Bytes()
    return
}

func main() {
    // o is output from openssl
    o, _ := exec.Command("openssl", "rsautl", "-sign", "-inkey", "t.key", "-in", "in.txt").Output()

    // t.key is private keyfile
    // in.txt is what to encode
    kt, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("t.key")
    e, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("in.txt")
    block, _ := pem.Decode(kt)
    privkey, _ := x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(block.Bytes)
    encData, _ := PrivateEncrypt(privkey, e)
    fmt.Println(encData)
    fmt.Println(o)
    fmt.Println(string(o) == string(encData))
}
```

---

**Update:** we can expect to have a native support for this kind of signing in Go 1.3, see [the appropriate commit](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/78c16c9b16dc9c64d1ddad6db5afaab12e87e8f2).

Comment: The link to the actual commits seems to be broken, I needed this kind of encryption also to sign a HTTP request. What is the exact name of this encryption because you have the PKCS naming etc?

Comment: Jerry, I've updated link to commit to github, the function you need is `rsa.SignPKCS1v15`

Answer (score 3):

Since go `1.3`, you can easily do this using `SignPKCS1v15`

```
rsa.SignPKCS1v15(nil, priv, crypto.Hash(0), signedData)
```

refer: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Golang-Nuts/Vocj33WNhJQ

Answer (score 1):

I stuck on this question for a while.

Eventually, I soleved that with the code here: 
https://github.com/bitmartexchange/bitmart-go-api/blob/master/bm_client.go

```
// Sign secret with rsa with PKCS 1.5 as the padding algorithm
// The result should be exactly same as "openssl rsautl -sign -inkey "YOUR_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY" -in "YOUR_PLAIN_TEXT""
signer, err := rsa.SignPKCS1v15(rand.Reader, rsaPrivateKey.(*rsa.PrivateKey), crypto.Hash(0), []byte(message))
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the joys of openssl... That is an incredibly poorly named function. If you poke around in the ruby code it's calling this openssl function

http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RSA_private_encrypt.html

Reading the documentation, this is actually signing the buffer with the private
key and not encrypting it.

DESCRIPTION

These functions handle RSA signatures at a low level.

RSA_private_encrypt() signs the flen bytes at from (usually a message digest      with an algorithm identifier) using the private key rsa and stores the signature   in to. to must point to RSA_size(rsa) bytes of memory.

Comment: Despite the documentation, this is actually a signing operation: you can perform the decryption step on the result and get back the original message. I assume it was intended to encrypt signatures, this conclusion is backed by comment in parentheses (see the description you cited): *usually a message digest with an algorithm identifier*.

Comment: In previous message I actually meant `RSA_private_encrypt` is an *encryption* operation, not signing.

Comment: @artyom The problem is that if you're "encrypting" within something that anyone with the **public** key can decrypt, you're not actually **encrypting** anything, in the sense that you're hiding it. There are very few good reasons to use this call to implement anything secure. To that extent, "private encrypt" is indeed closer to signing (where you'd "encrypt" a digest).